# Parent menu link # reloads the page instead of triggering submenu

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, menu, nav

How to prevent page reloading when empty link is pressed (href="#") it will just reload the page without triggering submenu.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure thing.  Can you please edit your question and add the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javascript:void(0);` instead of `#` to prevent the page from reloading
and then when the link is clicked you need to trigger the click event of its parent element :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="event.target.parentElement.click()">Produkter</a>
```

The below code is your event listener which is assigned to parent element of `link`,
it returns `false` when `event.target.nodeName` is `A`

```
'click_nav_child': function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'A')
        return false;
    var string = '';
    string += '<nav class="side-nav">';
    string += '<ul>';
    string += '<li class="prev"><a href="#">' + this.querySelector('a').textContent + '</a></li>' + this.querySelector('ul').innerHTML;
    string += '</ul>';
    string += '</nav>';
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.classList.add('nav-slide');
    itc_navigation.wrapper.appendChild(el);
    var slides = itc_navigation.get_slides();
    var last_slide = slides[slides.length - 1];
    last_slide.innerHTML = string;
    itc_navigation.change_slide('next');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Apparently you can also achieve this with css: `.child {
   pointer-events: none;
}`